# ¿Por qué me recorre mi if{}else{} mal cuando existe contenido en un array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

estoy intentando mostrar un botón según un usuario siga a otro o no. Cuando no hay contenido en la columna de la base de datos funciona bien, cambia de botón a dejar de seguir, pero si quiero seguir a otro usuario, le sigo, pero no me cambia el botón al de dejar de seguir. En cuanto al primer `if`, estoy comprobando si existe contenido en esa columna, si no me da error en el `foreach` ya que no puede recorrer un `array` vacio:

```
<?php
    $consultaSeguidor = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT id_usuario_seguido FROM seguidores WHERE id_usuario_seguidor='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $cuentaFilasSeguidores = mysqli_num_rows($consultaSeguidor);

    if($cuentaFilasSeguidores > 0)
    {
        $arraySeguidores = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaSeguidor);
        foreach($arraySeguidores as $key => $valor){
            if($valor == $id) {
        ?>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block ml-4" name="dejarseguir" value="Dejar de seguir"></input>
                </form>
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['dejarseguir']))
                {
                    $delete = mysqli_query($conexion, "DELETE FROM seguidores WHERE id_usuario_seguido='$id' AND id_usuario_seguidor='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
                    $seguidor = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET seguidores = seguidores-1 WHERE id = '$id'");

                    echo '<script>window.location="perfil.php?id='.$id.'"</script>';
                }
                else
                {}
                break;
            }
            else {
                ?>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-4" name="seguir" value="Seguir"></input>
                </form>

                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['seguir']))
                {
                    $add = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO seguidores (id_usuario_seguido,id_usuario_seguidor) VALUES ('$id','".$_SESSION['id']."')");
                    $seguidor = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET seguidores = seguidores+1 WHERE id = '$id'");

                    echo '<script>window.location="perfil.php?id='.$id.'"</script>';
                }
                else
                {}
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-4" name="seguir" value="Seguir"></input>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['seguir']))
            {
                $add = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO seguidores (id_usuario_seguido,id_usuario_seguidor) VALUES ('$id','".$_SESSION['id']."')");
                $seguidor = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET seguidores = seguidores+1 WHERE id = '$id'");

                echo '<script>window.location="perfil.php?id='.$id.'"</script>';
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La razon por la que no funciona es porque tienes que desplegar el boton despues de chequear si `$_POST['seguir']` esta disponible asi:

```
<form action="" method="POST">                    

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['seguir']))
            {
                $add = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO seguidores (id_usuario_seguido,id_usuario_seguidor) VALUES ('$id','".$_SESSION['id']."')");
                $seguidor = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE users SET seguidores = seguidores+1 WHERE id = '$id'");

                echo '<script>window.location="perfil.php?id='.$id.'"</script>';
                echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-4" name="dejarseguir" value="Dejar de Seguir"></input>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-4" name="seguir" value="Seguir"></input>';
            }

            break;
            ?>
</form>
```

Comment: y donde compruebo si un usuario sigue a otro?

Comment: Todo tu codigo se queda igual, mi respuesta solo es la parte de el else.de tu `if($valor== $id)` que creo que es donde verificas eso